# C++ pointer, reference and function call

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, reference

I am really new to C++ and I am a bit confused about pointers, adresses and function calls in C++.

I have the following function call:

```
config.pages= avail_pages(config.books_path, &config.books.front());
```

the config class has multiple `std::vectors<uint16_t>`, e.g. `config.books` holds the book ids (which are the file names from books_path).

Now I want to get the available pages of the first book (every page is a file). Therefore, avail_pages shall look for the files in books_path and for the first book.

A valid path to book 1234 and page 12 looks like this: books_path/1234/12

```
std::vector<uint16_t> avail_pages(std::string books_path, uint16_t* book) {

    std::vector<uint16_t> pages;

    std::string first_book;
    first_book = books_path + std::to_string(*book); //pointer or not? string concatenation?
    boost::filesystem::path p(first_book);

     for (auto i = boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(p); i != boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(); i++)
     {
             std::string s = i->path().filename().string();
             pages.push_back(std::stoi(s));
     }
  return pages;
}
```

The question is: if I use the vector function front() it returns a reference to the first element.

1. Do I call it like this: `&config.books.front()` ?
2. How do I pass the reference to a function? Do I have to use a pointer, like this: `std::vector<uint16_t> avail_pages(std::string books_path, uint16_t* book)` ?
3. How can I access the actual value and cast it from an integer to a
   string?

At the moment I am getting an error at the function call for the front() function which shows that I didnt understand the reference/ pointer thing.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it always part of some container? I mean the value that you want to reference.

Comment: Why are you passing the `book` argument as a pointer? Also, instead of passing `books_path` by value (which means it is *copied*) pass it as a constant reference (i.e. `const std::string& books_path`).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks for the hint with the constant reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be better if you provided definitions of config and books.
This being said, you need to understand than the vector function front() returns a reference to the front object held by the vector, this means you will typically call a class member after front. 
Consider this :

```
class book
{
public :
std::string books_path;
uint16_t book_id;
};
std::vector <book> config;
//your declared function :
std::vector<uint16_t> avail_pages(std::string books_path, uint16_t* book);
//you'd call this as such :
avail_pages(config.front().books_path, &config.front().book_id);
```